# Angular ui routing check condition before loading state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

Using angular [ui-router](http://ui-router.github.io/) I'm trying to make nested routing based on condition.i.e  Want to check a condition before loading a state.

```
    .state('main.home', {
        url: "/:cnt",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
            return template1;
        },
        controller: "myController",
        resolve: {
            //Some model
            }],

            lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$stateParams', function ($ocLazyLoad, $stateParams) {
               //lazily loaded controllers
            }]
        },
        onEnter: updateAppValues,
    }).state('main.home.default', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
            return template2;
        },
        resolve: {
            lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                //lazily loaded controllers
            }]
        },
        controller: 'myDefaultController',
    })
```

basically the nested router `main.home.default` must be loaded conditionally

```
if(something){
    //loaded state main.home.default
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can write a if condition in resolve and  in negative case use $location path to redirect to other route

Comment: Did you check if [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41824348/4927984) solved your issue? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the **event of route changing** with:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    if(next.$$route == 'routeYouWantToAvoid') { // Or whatever you want
        $state.transitTo('main.home.default');
    }
});
```

- `next` is the route you are going to.
- `current` the route you are coming from.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can add if condition in the resolve of main.home.default. ex:

```
 resolve:{
    "check":function($location){   
        if('Your Condition'){ 
            //Do something
        }else{
            $location.path('/');    //redirect user to home.
            alert("You dont belong here");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
   $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) { 
     if (toState.name == 'login'){ //if the name of that state is login
    //go to login page
      }
   });
});
```

Does this give you any idea? or

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state){
   $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      if(*your condition*) {
         $state.transitTo('stateYouWantToGo')
         event.preventDefault()
       }
    });
 });
```